# Foundation 4 - Margin/gutter between rows

Tags: css, zurb-foundation

I have a really simple question: how to I get a margin between rows in Foundation 4?

The following mark-up yields 3 spaced link images per row, but no gap between the rows. Maybe a 3 x 3 grid shouldn't be done like this. Otherwise, can Foundation do a square grid w/o additional CSS?

```
<div class="row">
  <a class="large-4 columns"><img /></a>
  <a class="large-4 columns"><img /></a>
  <a class="large-4 columns"><img /></a>
</div>
<div class="row">
  <a class="large-4 columns"><img /></a>
  <a class="large-4 columns"><img /></a>
  <a class="large-4 columns"><img /></a>
</div>
<div class="row">
  <a class="large-4 columns"><img /></a>
  <a class="large-4 columns"><img /></a>
  <a class="large-4 columns"><img /></a>
</div>
```

In the interests of time, I've implemented this as 9 left-floated elements, but I'm still curious about row spacing in Foundation.

Ta, Luke

Comment: there is `offset` class for spacing between floated elements `large-offset-1`... like this

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can override the default margin on the `.row` in CSS with `margin-bottom: 10px;`

Alternatively, a good way to implement a 3x3 grid of images in Foundation would be to use a 3-up **block grid**.

- Foundation 5 [block
  grid](http://foundation.zurb.com/sites/docs/v/5.5.3/components/block_grid.html)
- Foundation 6 [block grids](http://foundation.zurb.com/sites/docs/grid.html#block-grids)

Comment: Any idea why this does not work for me. It appears that foundation.css is overriding every css change I make to any row divs - regardless of where I put the css?

Answer (score 0):

I would also *highly* recommend using Sass to uniformly change this in a variety of ways in one place or inside a *partial* Sass file after importing the foundation partials.

For example, if you go the block grid route you can uniformly change it via the Sass variables provided by Zurb w/ Foundation 4:

```
$block-grid-elements: 12;
$block-grid-default-spacing: em-calc(20);
```

Alternatively you can do it individually using a mix-in like the following

```
.my-fancy-three-by-three
   +block-grid( $per-row: 3, $base-styles: true) 
   // If you're going mobile-first, and would do multiple block variants depending on various sizes, additional block-grid declerations are recommended from my personal experience should be FALSE in order to not have unnecessary code bloat.
```

If your  block variants are going to be simple and the pre-made media query sizes made available to you by Foundation 4 works with the overall design of what you're making, you can use build-in block classes such as `ul.small-block-grid-#`.

As far the overall grid,  it couldn't be simpler using the provided variables involving gaps that Foundation 4 provides:

```
  $block-grid-elements: 12
  $block-grid-default-spacing: emCalc(20px)
```

You can see more from the [docs](http://foundation.zurb.com/docs/components/block-grid.html) available for Foundation 4.

Comment: `em-calc` is being deprecated and `rem-calc` should be used instead.